# Can I get (IPR) Teeth filing done for braces?

Tags: hadith

Assalamualaikum,
I had braces when I was a teenager. It was my parents choice. For the treatment they removed 4 teeth. It's been about 6 years since. And my wisdom teeth grew in. This made my front teeth flare out, from the pushing of the new teeth. I really dislike my flared teeth. 
But the only way to fix them would be to either remove the wisdom teeth (which I don't want to do) or IPR. Which is when they shave a small amount between the teeth, so that the flared teeth can move back to their original position without any big extraction.

Would this be allowed?

JazakAllah Khairun

Comment: Why do you think it could not be allowed?

Comment: Assalamualaikum, sorry for my late response. I thought it would not be allowed because a hadith said for people not to file their teeth to look appear youthful, I don't know how authentic it is but that's why I wanted to get some opinions.